# NoReverseMatch at /home/ u'home' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from home import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/$', views.Home, name="home"),
    url(r'^services/$', views.Services),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.Contact)
)
```

But when I remove the 'namespace="home"' section, I get a 'NoReverseMatch at /home/ u'home' is not a registered namespace'. I've chanted the code around many times, but it's always one of those two errors. The docs aren't much help.

home.html:

```
{% url 'home' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block doctype %}<!DOCTYPE HTML>{% endblock %}
{% load i18n %}
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}{% trans "name of website" %}</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        {% block meta_tags %}{% endblock %}
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-wide.css" />
        </noscript>
        {% block stylesheet %}{% endblock %}
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
        {% block js %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body class="{% block bodyclass %}{% endblock%}">
        {% block page %}
            <div id="header">{% block header_navigation %}
                    <h1><a href="home.html" id="logo">%{% trans "name of website" %}<em>description of stuff</em></a></h1>
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="current"><a href="{% url 'home:home.html' %}">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'home:services.html' %}">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'home:contact.html' %}">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
```

Comment: `namespace` is parameter to `include()` not `url()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is called `name` not `namespace`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/$', views.Home, name="home"),
    url(r'^services/$', views.Services, name="services"),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.Contact, name="contact"),
)
```

And then in the template:

```
<li class="current"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'services' %}">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact Us</a></li>
```

Comment: still getting the same error - with the template tag as well. I've placed this tag many places within the template itself (but only one placement per attempt) and still get the same error when I reload.

Comment: Which error: "unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'" or "NoReverseMatch"?

Comment: You shouldn't use the namespace (`home:`) and file extension (`.html`) here: `{% url 'home:home.html' %}`. Valid tag is `{% url 'home' %}`.  See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

`namespace` is not a valid `url` parameter, you need to use `name` keyword.

```
url(r'^home/$', views.Home, name="home"),
```

And then you can use `{% url 'home' %}` without problem.

Comment: it's now a "NoReverseMatch at /home/" error. Ideas?

Comment: @11119 you need to reset your server. after change urls.py code.